# Load a TensorFlow .pb model using Hugging Face Transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I want to load a model that I saved after training. The original model was built on TensorFlow, and the `saved_model` path has the .pb files:

```
assets/
fingerprint.pb
keras_metadata.pb
saved_model.pb
variables/
```

My goal is to load this model using the Hugging Face `transformers` library. I read that it is possible with the `AutoModel`, but I have not figured out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModel

model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("<path_to_saved_pretrained_model>")
```

Comment: I actually tried this with both the `AutoModel` and the `TFAutoModel`, and I get this error in both scenarios:

`OSError: ../../../Projects/pneumonia-xray/models/pneumonia_classifier/ does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/../../../Projects/pneumonia-xray/models/pneumonia_classifier//None' for available files.`

Comment: how did you save your model? can you share the code?